# Japanese equivalent of saying to keep something to yourself?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

What's the Japanese equivalent to saying for people to keep something to themselves?

Like, "Keep your toilet humour to yourself," or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could say it in several different ways:
"keep ... to oneself" 「人に言わない（でおく）」「人に話さない（でおく）」「人に[明]{あ}かさない」「[秘密]{ひみつ}にする/しておく」「[胸]{むね}/[心]{こころ}(の中/のうち)に[秘]{ひ}めておく」「胸に[納]{おさ}めておく」「胸/心にしまっておく」「他人に知らせない」 etc.

And you could translate it in different ways depending on context, for example:

> - Keep your opinions to yourself. とやかく意見を言うなよ。(ジーニアス英和辞典)
> - Keep your opinions to yourself! 君の意見など聞きたくもない。([ランダムハウス英和大辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/ej/618620/meaning/m0u/))
> - He often keeps his opinions to himself. 彼は自分の意見を人に言わないことがよくある。([研究社英和中辞典](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/keep+to+oneself))
> - I'll keep the secret to myself until death. 死ぬまでその秘密は守ります。(ジーニアス英和辞典)

Comment: How about a somewhat ironic tone, like 言わなくていい, 言わないといい ?

Comment: @Rightleg Yes, I think 言わなくていい would work, eg 「つまらない冗談言わなくていい！」「余計なこと言わなくていい」